# How to write the formula for a two way lookup value in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a Excel formula to display the Date if it finds 'A3'(between D7:H7) in a row by matching with Coulmn value 'A3' and similarly with next rows.

Below is the Table Looks like and the required Output:
[image: Required Output]

I am using Index and Match function to solve this but not successful.

Below is the formula I tried:

=INDEX(D7:H7,MATCH(C7,C7:C10,0),MATCH(D7,D7:H7,0))

My aim is to display the Month with respect to the Column Value matching with that particular row. Please correct me in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are being more complex than you need. And a bit redundunt, too.
You will create a correct formula (right use of $ ) for cell C7, and then you will drag-copy it to C8 etc. The seperate `MATCH(D7,D7:H7,0)` part you wrote is not needed at all. Also, the INDEX needs to contain only the months, and since it is in the same row regardless of the row for which you are making the calculations, you need to add $ before the 6. Try this (remember, paste this into C7 and then drag-copy):

```
=INDEX(D$6:H$6,,MATCH(C7,C7:C10,0))
```

Comment: I tried with your formula pasting in C7 but the vlaue is displayed as '0' for cell C7

Comment: I modified your formula and copied in cell B7 then got the Output as I required =INDEX($D$6:$H$6;MATCH(C7;D7:H7;0)) and drag down to next cells. Thank you for the formula it helped me.